# How can i change google account that accept Firebase App Distribution invitation?

Tags: android, firebase, google-fabric, google-account, firebase-app-distribution

I receive an Firebase App Distribution invitation on my *corporate* google account. But when I accept invitation by clicking on "**Go setup**" in email, I mistakenly accepted the invitation with my *personal* google account in my Android phone.
I have tried to re-accept invitation with my *corporate* google account, but **App Tester** app say:

> Invitation has already been accepted

I have tried to revoked my access in Firebase Console, and add my *corporate* google account again. But it keep invitation state has "**accepted**". There is a way to remove app from a google account to be able to accept invitation again with another account ? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Chintan from Firebase. Once you accept an invitation, you can’t change the account that accepts the invitation. You’d have to delete the tester from the project in the “Testers” tab then re-invite to a release.

Comment: Remove & add email again from Testers tab did the trick. Thanks !

Comment: This message 'Invitation has already been accepted' really makes confused and not helpful.

Comment: again, terrible user experiance by google

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure about my solution, but what I just did was:

1. uninstall the Firebase App Tester app (with the yellow icon) because it doesn't have the account settings;
2. open the invite on your corporate email, and tap on the **Get started** button to open the web mobile version of the Firebase Distribution app;
3. choose your personal account, and then tap on the small gear icon to show some options;
4. there will be a an option do **Delete your account**. Tap on it.
5. you will be logged out;
6. (I repeated the steps 3-5 with my corporate account, just to be sure);
7. close everything, open the invite again, tap on the **Get started** button;
8. alternate to your corporate account;
9. accept everything;
10. download the app.

Comment: I tried it and I can confirm you can delete your account. Unfortunately, if you want to reuse the same email to accept the same invitation, then you need someone that clean-up your email related data from the firebase console